# Does Visual Studio vNext have support for "go to definition" from F# projects to projects written in other languages

Tags: debugging, f#, intellisense, visual-studio-2012, f#-3.0

I do a lot of cross-language development where F# code consumes C# libraries.  Lack of ability to F12 to go to definition is THE major annoyance in VS2010.  I did not notice anything about this on the [What's New](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh370982%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page, but then it could be a tooling issue, not necessarily a language issue.  Same question for Shift-F12, find all references.

Please help me to make a decision to upgrade (or not).

Comment: In 2 days, the vNext beta is released and you'll be able to try this yourself.

Comment: I am willing to wait til Feb 29th (I heard the news on Channel 9 last night).  I'd like for somebody to try this for me.  This should save an hour per curious developer.  If I have a question, then I am sure there's a thousand others with a similar question.

Comment: I'm a curious dev, so I'll grab it the second it's released. For those who aren't curious enough to install it, I'll be happy to try F12 and share my results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just installed VS 11 and made a solution with an F# executable and a C# dll. The F# code calls the a function in the C# code, and the debugger traces into the C# code just as it should, but the result of pressing F12 is still only "**Cannot navigate to definition. Source code is not available.**".

BTW, the new look makes it very hard to distinguish tabs, property panes, toolbars etc from the grey background. It all just looks like grey on grey, like something dreamed up in the former Republic of East Germany.

Comment: Erich Honecker's interior decorator, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is vague, but I seemed to 'magically' gain the ability to 'go to definition' (also via ctrl-clicking on the code item) in VS2010.  I think this was when I installed the F# Power Pack.

Comment: I don't believe in Magic.  F12 works from F# to F#, but does nothing from F# to a referenced definition of a public and callable method in C#.  Even with the F# Power Pack 2.0.

Comment: Sorry, it must be the coffee talking :)